# A 2nd Order Constant-Coefficients Differential Equation - General Solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a 2nd order differential equation here. The main thing I need help for is working out what the general solution will take the form of. The equation I have is: $$ \ddot{x}+2\xi\omega\dot{x}+\omega^2x=0$$
I can solve for the constants but I just don't really know what general solution to look for and more importantly how to go about looking for it.

Comment: You "can solve for the constants". What constants? If you show the work you've done and where you are stuck we'll be able to help you understand.

Comment: That said, the general method is to substitute $x(t) = e^{t\lambda}$ and solve the quadratic in $\lambda$.

Comment: Are $\omega,\xi$ constants? If so, use $x''=x'\frac{dx'}{dx}$

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that $x$ stands for $x(t)$. So, for $$\ddot{x}+2\xi\omega\dot{x}+\omega^2x=0$$ the characteristic equation is, as usual, $$r^2+2\xi\omega r+\omega^2=0$$ for which you get the roots $$r_{1,2}=-\xi  \omega\pm \omega\sqrt{\left(\xi ^2-1\right) }$$ and the general solution is $$x(t)=c_1 e^{r_1t}+c_2 e^{r_2t}$$

Comment: Unless, of course, $\xi=\pm1$.

Comment: Aren't you tired to be always right ? Thanks for pointing. Cheers.